# How do you view EOT webfont files?

Tags: webfonts, eot

With so many people using EOT files for webfonts (to support IE8) I can't believe I am unable to find a single application that supports viewing them.  Hopefully I'm missing something obvious but when I Google "eot file viewer" I find nothing but a couple possible virus-looking websites (the ones that have like 1 million different download links all leading to different sites with random junk on them).

I'm working on a PC but also have a Mac available, I have Visual Studio, XCode, Adobe CS3 suite, and a slew of other developer/graphics tools.  Of course all of the popular web browsers as well.

I'm troubleshooting a webfont display issue in IE8.  It is using my EOT file, but not displaying it exactly as I think it should be.  I'd like to rule out anything lost in the conversion issue (I've used web squirl and ufonts and other online converters), which I can only do if I can view the EOT directly not convert to some other format first, or convert some other format to EOT and "assume" it is the same.

Comment: Since .eot is supported by IE6+, couldn't you simply compare IE8 to IE9/10/11?

Comment: Voting to close as a tool request. In the 4 years of its existence, this question has only attracted link-only answers, including possible spam and self-promotion.

Answer (score 4):

if you don't mind converting eot to any other format first like ttf for example, then you can convert it by using my tool [onlinefontconverter.com](https://onlinefontconverter.com)

Comment: what tool are you using in the backend for converting eot fonts?

Comment: [It appears](https://github.com/jimmywarting/ofc) you are affiliated with onlinefontconverter.com. Please note that our [self-promotion policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497) requires you to disclose this information in answers like this one.

Answer (score 2):

**Fontexplorer X Pro** (not free) is able to create a preview of EOT fonts:

http://www.fontexplorerx.com/trial-pro/

Here's a description taken from their website: "**Import, organize and preview Web Fonts (WOFF and EOT formats)**"

Answer (score 2):

http://www.pkmurphy.com.au/glyphviewer/, maybe?  It appears legit, but only supports loading fonts by URL and not by uploading a file.